Asymptotic behavior of $\sum_{p\leq N} \frac{A^p}{p}$
I've been trying to find the asymptotic growth of $\sum_{p\leq N} \frac{A^p}{p}$, where $A$ is some positive integer and the sum is over all primes $p$ up to some large bound $N$. For $A=1$, this grows as $\log(\log(N))$ as is well-known. For $A\geq2$, which is the case I'm interested in, I've tried partial summation (either using $a_p=1$, $a_p=1/p$, $a_p=A^p$ or $a_p=\frac{A^p}{p}$), but nothing really seems to work. Can anyone please help me out? Is there another strategy I can use?
PS: In general when using partial summation, is there a rule of thumb on what is the best way to use it? E.g. trying to make $a_p$ as big or small as possible? Or is there something similar along those lines?
Thank you very much for your help!

My guess is $$ \sum_{p\le N}\frac{A^p}{p} ~\sim~ \int_2^N \frac{A^t}{t}\frac{{\rm d}t}{\ln t} ~\sim~ {\rm Ei}((\ln A)N). $$

Partial summation is the discrete version of integration by parts thus the "rules" are the same : you do it when you are happy to replace a factor by its (discrete) derivative and the other one by its (discrete) anti-derivative. Here, the fact to sum on a set of prime numbers makes it pretty hard to use.
Instead, notice there is an important difference between the case $A = 1$ and $A > 1$ : $\frac{1}{p} \rightarrow 0$ while $\frac{A^p}{p} \rightarrow +\infty$ if $A > 1$. In this case, you can use the fact that when $u_n \sim v_n$, then $\sum u_n \sim \sum v_n$. Therefore, knowing an asymptotic development of $\sum_{p \leqslant N} \frac{A^p}{p}$ is slightly harder than knowing one for $\frac{A^{p_n}}{p_n}$ where $(p_n)$ is the prime numbers sequence.
We know that $p_n \sim n\ln(n)$, however, being able to give a simple equivalent of $A^{p_n}$ is the same problem as determining an asymptotic development of $(p_n)$ at order $\mathrm{o}(1)$. I don't know a lot about this kind of development but the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem (section : approximation for the $n$th prime number) only gives a development at order $\mathrm{o}\!\left(\frac{n}{\ln(n)^2}\right)$. For this reason, I belive your problem is very hard to solve.
All I can think of right know is to find some bounds. For example, using $\frac{A^p}{N} \leqslant \frac{A^p}{p} \leqslant \frac{A^N}{p}$, you deduce,
$$
\frac{A^N}{N} \leqslant \frac{1}{N}\sum_{p \leqslant N} A^p \leqslant \sum_{p \leqslant N} \frac{A^p}{p} \leqslant A^N\sum_{p \leqslant N} \frac{1}{p} \sim \ln(\ln(N))A^N.
$$
Once more, you still have to compute an equivalent of $\sum_{p \leqslant N} A^p$ for the lower bound, where the exact same issues as previously appear.
Maybe you should try first to find asymptotic developments of sequences that grow slower like,
$$
\ln\left(\sum_{p \leqslant N} \frac{A^p}{p}\right), \qquad \left(\sum_{p \leqslant N} \frac{A^p}{p}\right)^{1/N}.
$$
Notice that in particular, the second one converges toward $A$.
